# How to create a unique primary key in Entity Framework using GUID and regenerate GUID if duplicate is found?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a CodeFirst Entity Framework database.  I am generating a GUID myself, and the following is defined in the model:

```
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string BatchId { get; set; }
```

My goal - is there a way I can first validate that the GUID does not already exist in the database, and then create a new GUID as needed until a unique one is found?

Comment: Eh... You do know what the 'U' in 'GUID' stands for, don't you?

Comment: [Represents a globally unique identifier (GUID).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx)

Comment: Correct, it is unique.  But if it is created too quickly and the clock hasn't moved, there is a possibility for duplicates to be made I believe, so I wanted to make sure that could not happen.

Comment: `-1` pendraggon87 run some stress test and let us know if and when you find that duplicate GUID.. you would have a better chance of winning the Lottery or getting struck twice by lightning GUID Wiki it

Comment: Duplicate GUIDs? No, if that were so your generator would be seriously broken. The time is only used for seeding, and it is a small part of the randomness. However, you have to be aware that (random) GUIDs as primary keys can hurt your DB performance really bad.

Comment: pendraggon87   do you know the algorithm for generating GUIDs in .net?  "But if it is created too quickly and the clock hasn't moved" where did you read that ?  just a little sample to get the concept http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149139/how-evenly-spread-are-the-first-four-bytes-of-a-guid-created-in-net

Comment: I vote to close this ..it definitely can't help anyone in the near future..

Comment: @pendraggon87: You really should read up on the topic, before making such assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By all means read the DB first to be sure to be sure.  But E=MC^2 or your money back.

```
Context.DbSet.find(MyGuid);
```

Nope not found.... 
Let us know when you get a dup if using Guid.New();

Btw do you plan on using strings for your gUid or type Guid / DBType UniqueIdentier ? If so, You should reconsider the type chosen.

Comment: And what happens when two duplicate GUIDS are created, they both check and find it's not there, and then add the item.  You need to use a transaction to both check and then add the item or not for this to be a viable option.  (Or avoid the problem entirely and let the DB generate the ID.)

Comment: Seeing as you have 27k rep, I'll just assume you're trolling, @Servy. The alternative is embarrassing.

Comment: @Trickery If you assume that your GUIDs are properly generated and never have duplicates then there is no reason to check, if you know that you're using a identifier generation method that has the potential for collisions (in a practical sense) then you need to check *properly*.  My point is that you shouldn't be doing this at all, but if you do do it, at least do it right.

Comment: You can't generate two similar Guids, since a Guid, by definition, is globally unique. If you're generating some sort of ID on your own that can conflict with itself, it is no longer a Guid. So no, you can't have duplicate **Guids**.

Comment: Fair comment about doing properly if you going to do it. But i think a easy how do I quickly find the if the KEY is used, was what he wanted.  The fact that is makes no sense is most likely now clear by the rest of the comments :-)

Comment: @Trickery Technically, yes, if you attempt to write a guid generation algorithm and it fails it's not a GUID, but that doesn't mean that the OP isn't calling it a GUID anyway.  My point still stands though.  You shouldn't need to do this at all, because they shouldn't conflict, but if you do need to do this check because your identifiers aren't unique then this method fails to accomplish that goal as it has a very obvious race condition.  It's also worth noting that *technially* existing guid algorithms can collide, it's just very, very unlikely, so by your definition they're not GUIDs.

Comment: Fair enough, I see what you meant now. Sorry for jumping down your throat.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a `Guid`, it is a `string`; it is better you to declare it as a `Guid`, then you do not need to worry.

Practically, the same `Guid` will not be generated in the same machine twice. Thus you do not need to worry if you change your property to:

```
[Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid BatchId { get; set; }
```

Comment: The same GUID will not be generated twice *globally*.

Comment: Or you could just have an identity column and be sure that it's unique (for that table) while consuming less memory, processor cycles, and developer effort...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth the same GUID can be produced theoretically, but "Such an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated."

Comment: @daryal: Indeed. The way you formulated it, it sounded as if it was only guaranteed on a machine scope and a second machine could easily produce the same GUID - which is not the case.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth you are right, maybe because of improper wording.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an old code I made myself:

```
private static IQueryable<MyData> FetchFromDatabase(MyContainer context, Guid guid)
{
    if (!context.DatabaseExists())
        throw Constants.ExceptionDatabaseMissing;

    return from data in context.MyDataSet
           where data.GUID.Equals(guid)
           select data;
}
```

Just check if the return value contains anything. If yes, you have a duplicate.

Comment: And what happens when two duplicate GUIDS are created, they both check and find it's not there, and then add the item.  You need to use a transaction to both check and then add the item or not for this to be a viable option.  (Or avoid the problem entirely and let the DB generate the ID.)

Comment: @Servy My old code was meant for revisioning. Duplicate GUIDs were common there, because every revision of the same branch had the same GUID. I used this code to find any and all data from the same branch (different names), and to make sure that nobody could upload data with different GUID but same names (name-conflicts). Like I said, it's old code. I don't expect anybody to just copy-paste the thing into their own code.