# Exponentially deteriorating performance on inserts in SQL Server Compact 4.0 tables with an Identity column

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, identity-column

EDIT: the issue below has been fixed in the Entity Framework 6.

Running the code below takes a disappointing 2 minutes and 10 seconds. Running it a second time takes 6.5 minutes. This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740710/is-using-a-sequential-guid-the-only-viable-alternative-to-a-database-generated/14745976#comment20661044_14745976)

```
Private Sub RunTest()
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
        sw.Restart()
        Using db As New TestDB
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = False
            For n = 1 To 100
                For m = 1 To 100
                    db.Tops.Add(New Top)
                Next
            Next
            db.SaveChanges()
        End Using
        MsgBox(sw.Elapsed.ToString)
    End Sub
```

The Entity:

```
Public Class Top
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        One = "arerjlwkerjglwejrglwergoiwerhgiowehrowerlwelfvbwlervbowerghpiweurhgpiwuerviiervljwebbrlvjnepvjnweprvupiweurv"
        Two = "w;lrjgwwergkjwervgjwelrgjhwelghlwekglwergiuwehrgwjergjwervgjwerjgnwekrngpwergjpowergllwejrnglkwerngpoierhpiiuewrpjwenrwenrv;lwenrvkjernpgpsrvpi"

    End Sub

    'ID'
    Public Property ID As Integer

    'NATIVE PROPERTIES'
    Public Overridable Property One As String
    Public Overridable Property Two As String

    'NAVIGATION PROPERTIES'

End Class
```

Moving the Using block inside the second level interation and calling SaveChanges there makes it only worse.

TestDB just inherits DBContext without any further configuration.When I disable database generation of the Top.ID property and supply the ID myself the performance improves a thirty fold.This problem makes using Database generated ID's in SQL Server Compact impossible. Is there a solution other than using client side generated IDs?

Comment: Is it possible for you to test whether this also happens in a server version of sql server (express)?

Comment: @GertArnold it is. I will let you know later this day. I read that this problem seems to be specific to the Compact version though.

Comment: Could you share a CREATE TABLE script? (Created by the Sql Compact Toolbox)

Comment: Connect the toolbox to thev sdf file in your bin/bebug folder, and create the script

Comment: Interestingly, the same code runs in milliseconds with ObjectContext - I will try to dig further

Comment: @ErikEJ Thanks! We are on the verge of implementing this database and the decision how to generate the primary keys is of course pivotal.

Comment: I have just done some testing - use Guid.NewGuid() is my suggestion

Comment: @ErikEJ That amounts to using a client generated ID. I know that that is *a lot* faster. It seems that this problem must some kind of bug. Why else do SQL Express and using ObjectContext not suffer from it?

Comment: Yes, it is most likely a bug, but you do not have time to wait for a fix. Log an issue on  the Codeplex site or connect

Comment: @ErikEJ I logged the issue on CodePlex. Will you upvote it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue, it is caused by the statement to get the generated id causing table scans, I propose a fix here, tested with 4000 entities, down from 17 secs to 2 secs. http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/857 - it will be include in the EF6 build after Alpha 3

Comment: Or other approaches were suggested, expecting it to be by design - turned out to be by poor design

Comment: The issue was fixed for EF 6.