# Evenly spread files in directories using UUID splits

Tags: hash, uuid

I am investigating the best way to build an evenly distributed two level directory structure for storing files received by a distributed application (files come in with no file name).  To achieve this, my initial plan was to take the first two chars of a hash string for directory 1 and the next two for directory 2 e.g.:

A hash of **67ca**bf2cf7418461ad53d9fd7e067049 can be used to store a file by the same name in a directory structure as follows: **/67/ca/** 67cabf2cf7418461ad53d9fd7e067049

I then realised that as I have to create a unique file name (UUID) for each incoming 'blob' perhaps I could just use the first four characters of the UUID itself saving myself the need to hash the UUID.  e.g.:

A UUID of **ea5d**c4cf-1b91-4a8f-8d56-69b7223d8954 can be used to store a file by the same name in a directory structure as follows:
**/ea/5d/** ea5dc4cf-1b91-4a8f-8d56-69b7223d8954

I have a good understanding of the uniqueness of UUIDs but I can't find any decisive explanation as to whether the randomness of the first four characters will be as evenly spread as the first four characters of a hash especially given that the first octet is rooted in a timestamp (source https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122).

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149139/how-evenly-spread-are-the-first-four-bytes-of-a-guid-created-in-net) previous question but it seems far from decisively answered!

Is anyone able to help me understand this better or explain why the spread may or may not be as even as a hash?

Comment: There are several versions of uuid. UUID Version 5 uses a SHA1 hash, so I think it should be suitable for your need.

Comment: There are also some uuid generation schemes that this would not work well for. E.g. on CentOS 7.x, `uuidgen -t` generates a time-based string that appears to sequentially increase in the first segment, which would not work very well for using the first couple of bytes...

Comment: I would be looking at using UUID version 4 due to it being random rather than namespace based.

Answer (score 11):

So, I ran a test with a set of 10,000,000 UUIDs (version 4) and I conclude that the spread is very even.  The results are as follows, I hope it helps someone.

```
+---------------+------------+--+----------------+------------+
| First 2 chars | frequency  |  | Second 2 chars | frequency  |
+---------------+------------+--+----------------+------------+
| ea            | 39781      |  | 3c             | 39624      |
+---------------+------------+--+----------------+------------+
| 57            | 39589      |  | 6e             | 39575      |
+---------------+------------+--+----------------+------------+
| 63            | 39566      |  | f6             | 39524      |
+---------------+------------+--+----------------+------------+
| etc.          | etc.       |  | etc.           | etc.       |
+---------------+------------+--+----------------+------------+
| middle rows of results removed to keep this concise.        |
+---------------+------------+--+----------------+------------+
+---------------+------------+--+----------------+------------+
| b3            | 38455      |  | cf             | 38572      |
+---------------+------------+--+----------------+------------+
| f8            | 38454      |  | 4a             | 38549      |
+---------------+------------+--+----------------+------------+
| d7            | 38448      |  | b1             | 38540      |
+---------------+------------+--+----------------+------------+
| Total         | 10,000,000 |  |                | 10,000,000 |
+---------------+------------+--+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: If anyone finds this answer insightful or useful please feel free to help build my reputation.

Comment: Can you please post the code you used for this test so we can see the results ourselves?

Comment: Thanks! this was very useful for something I am working on and saved me a bunch of time.

Comment: Nice work - this answered a question I was investigating regarding partition keys on cosmosdb

Comment: Hi @bunoi, you saved a lot of my time. Can you provide me the script by which you did the test?